# Do most pseudorandom number generators produce a cyclic sequence of unique numbers?

Tags: random

Saw the formula for a pseudorandom number generator in BASIC ages ago and it used each pseudorandom number as the seed for the next one. So if it hit the same number after a while, it would cycle the same sequence all over again and therefore the numbers in the sequence were all different.

1. Would the sequence include the complete set of numbers from 0 to 2^16-1 for the 16 bit version of this generator, all appearing once?
2. Is this what happens in most pseudorandom number generators in most languages even today?

Comment: What has your research led you to? Reading the [Wikipedia article on random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) would probably be more informative than any answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

*All* pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) have cycles; they all rely on a state which can be expressed as a big number with a specific end. Once that end is reached, the cycle starts again. Some PRNGs have only one cycle, others have several, and still others *devolve* to a cycle. "[Random Invertible Mappings](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/random-invertible-mapping-statistics.html)" has diagrams.

For example, the Mersenne Twister PRNG has a state of 19968 bits (and so has a state that can express any number less than 2^19968), so it will have a cycle no bigger than 2^19968 (and in fact it's less, namely about 2^19937).

Comment: Is a PRNG possible with a cycle equal to the number of states, in other words where all states in the range 0 to 2^N-1 are possible?

Comment: Yes.  One example is a _full-period_ linear congruential generator with the right parameters (e.g., section 3 of L'Ecuyer 1999, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure")